# Adding and removing a content with the same button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, click

I know how to add the content from `ul id="menu"`, to `<p id="demo"></p>`, by using a button. But I don't know how to remove it(or hide), with the same button??? That's like a dropdown, but a more simple. I only need to hide this content or **return the opposite action**. 
**Thank you in advanced**
Here my code

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var addInner = document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = addInner;
  });
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Contacts</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Main</li>
</ul>
<button>Click to addInnerContent</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Keep track of how many times the button has been clicked. modulo 2 it to get if its even or odd. Depending on if its even or odd perform a different action in the event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a small change `if(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML == ""){` and in else `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML == ""` . That does your code if your element demo was empty before, but if it was not then it removes everything from demo element.

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var addInner = document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML;
    if(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML == ""){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = addInner;
    }else{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    }
  });
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Contacts</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Main</li>
</ul>
<button>Click to addInnerContent</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```